# How to pass args to the python shell

Tags: python

I would like to play around with the items in `sys.argv` from within the python shell. Is there a way to pass arbitrary arguments, such as:

```
$ python one two three
```

And that it would open up the python shell and I could get the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
# ['python', 'one', 'two', three'],  or ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: `python -h` is your friend here :)

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound right, but where do I get more information on `-` ? It just gives a one-liner that I can't make sense of (which I copy-pasted below).

Comment: It seems like your questions here are really more about the command line (or about shells such as bash) than about Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass those arguments after a hyphen, such as:

`$ python - one two three`

In this case, `sys.argv` will yield `['-', 'one', 'two', 'three']`

[Here is a link that will help you with such arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options)

Comment: thanks. I see `-      : program read from stdin (default; interactive mode if a tty)` in the help. Is that the sole purpose of `-` or does it have other uses?

Comment: When not in interactive mode, it can be used to pipe commands from the previous shell command, such as `echo print(1, 2, 3) | python -` (prints `1 2 3`)

Comment: you can use the argsparse() to be actively functional for python as well

Comment: @Marco -- thanks. Want to add this link into your answer and I'll accept it? https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options

Comment: @$ echo print(1,2,3)|python -
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ?

Comment: @David542 Sorry, I forgot to escape the print, it should be `echo "print(1, 2, 3)" | python -`